# Qual é o meu limite ao editar uma resposta de outrem?

Tags: debate, edição, respostas

Eu quis ter uma boa intenção ao editar uma publicação hoje.

Adicionei um conteúdo adicional, que devo concordar que realmente foi bem  "generoso" (falo em questão de quantidade de informações adicionadas).

A saber foi numa pergunta que eu fiz, onde eu recebi uma resposta sobre como resolver o problema,  mas que, **na minha opinião**, deveria ter algum comentário explicando "o porquê" de funcionar.

A saber, foi essa edição:

[image: Edição generosa do @Wallace :D]

https://pt.stackoverflow.com/revisions/146822/3

Na qual foi revertida para essa, pelo @Gabe

https://pt.stackoverflow.com/revisions/146822/4

Houve então um pequeno debate no chat sobre eu dever ou não dever editar publicações, adicionando muitos detalhes ao conteúdo. Resolvi fazer a pergunta aqui, pois o lugar certo de discutir é aqui no meta! (uhu!!!)

Na verdade, só pensei que a resposta deveria ter mais explicações, porém a minha atitude de editar não foi aprovada por alguns.

**Observação**: Não estou aqui choramingando por ter tido  minha edição revertida, só quero saber como posso melhor evitar algum tipo de situação onde eu possa estar confundido mais que ajudando, ou que com boas intenções eu possa estar prejudicando a alguém

Qual é o meu limite ao editar uma publicação de outrem?

Deveria realmente adicionar aquela informação, ou publicar uma resposta de complemento (como eu acabei fazendo)?

Se o conteúdo for alterado em grande escala, é sempre preferível fazer uma resposta complementando?

Comment: Eu geralmente comento para pessoa complementar se quiser, e se ela não usa, eu publico em separado. Se for coisa bem votada, e o usuário anda sumido do site, no máximo eu arrumo eventual erro que comprometa a resposta.

Comment: @Bacco Isso era óbvio, mas desta vez eu fui cabeção e esqueci de perguntar para o AR seu eu pudia adicionar complemento ou não à resposta.

Comment: @Bacco concordo.

Comment: O que eu penso sobre isso já está respondido aqui: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/644/101

Answer (score 10):

Eu vou dar minha opinião, apesar de não ter acompanhado o caso especifico, ou seja vou citar algo que acho que deve ser usado na maior parte dos casos.

1. Se é apenas um acréscimo de um detalhe que não mude o sentido da resposta e ela já é razoável/boa o suficiente, então editar pode ser legal.
2. Se a resposta é razoável, mas falta algo essencial, ou você tem uma informação mais extensa sobre o assunto então editar pode ser uma péssima ideia, isso porque em boa parte dos casos pode conflitar com a intenção do autor, o melhor é formular uma resposta mais detalhada, afinal de contas não deixará de ser uma contribuição.
3. Se a resposta é simples e mesmo que considerada razoável e resolva o problema, mas ainda sim for **fraca** ou faltar algo **essencial**/**fundamental** é altamente recomendado formular uma resposta nova.

Sobre o 2 e 3, digo isso porque muitos usuários são iniciantes no site, as vezes um comentário basta pra apontar o que pode ser melhorado, mas nem sempre levam isso para o lado bom, principalmente novatos.

Se for um usuário mais experiente e participativo, um comentário bastará, mas na maioria dos outros casos não vai dar certo, o melhor é ensinar pelo exemplo, ou seja se você postar uma boa/ótima resposta e ganhar maior notoriedade que a outra, ele irá perceber e irá provavelmente tentar melhorar na próxima.

Comment: Ia formular uma resposta, mas esta vai de encontro ao que eu penso em todos os pontos.

Comment: Se considerar relevante, opte por deixar um comentário como a sua resposta menciona algo que a outra não mencionou.

Comment: Obrigado @BrunoCosta no entanto não entendi bem aonde sugeri que eu comentei com o link da minha resposta, seria abaixo da pergunta ou nas outras respostas? Ou se refere a alguma outra pergunta no META?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Eu não percebi muito bem o que você disse. Mas a minha sugestão é que caso o AP faça uma resposta, então ele pode também deixar um comentário na sua resposta dizendo onde ela é diferente das outras. Isto se ele considerar relevante. Eu já fiz isso duas ou tres vezes noutras comunidades.

Comment: @BrunoCosta entendi agora se refere ao problema citado aqui, pensei que estava a se referir a algo do META. A sua sugestão é um boa ideia, mas não recomendo pois nem todos usuário levam muito bem este tipo de situação, claro que é direito e recomendável apontar problemas, afinal as perguntas servirão para futuros visitantes. Se for um usuário experiente, talvez ele entenda o comentário como uma critica construtiva, mas usuários mais novos podem não levar muito bem, talvez seja melhor apontar o problema das demais respostas na sua nova resposta. Mas todavia a sua ideia é boa.

Answer (score 6):

#### O que o nosso "irmão mais velho" fala sobre isso?

Existem [várias perguntas no meta.SE](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=edit%20answers) sobre esse assunto, então irei apenas colocar alguns pontos que achei interessante que foi dito em uma resposta:

> #### Por que as pessoas podem editar os meus posts? Como o trabalho de edição?
>
> Todas as contribuições são licenciados sob Creative Commons, e este site é editado colaborativamente, como a Wikipedia. Se você ver algo que precisa ser melhorado, clique em editar!
>
> A edição é importante para manter perguntas e respostas claras, relevantes e up-to-date. Se você não está confortável com a idéia de suas contribuições sendo editado colaborativamente por outros usuários confiáveis, isso pode não ser o local para você.
>
> #### Quando devo editar mensagens?
>
> Toda vez que você ver um post que precisa ser melhorado e estão inclinados a sugerir uma edição, você está convidado a fazê-lo. O autor original de uma pergunta ou resposta pode sempre editar o seu próprio posto, independentemente do nível de reputação.
>   Edições são esperados para ser substancial e melhor deixar o cargo que você o encontrou. As razões mais comuns para as edições incluem:
>
> - Para corrigir erros ortográficos e gramaticais
> - Para esclarecer o
>     significado da mensagem (sem mudar esse significado)
> - Para incluir    informações adicionais encontrados apenas em
>     observações, então toda    a informação relevante para o cargo está
>     contido em um só lugar
> - Para    corrigir erros menores ou adicionar atualizações como o post
>     idades
>     Para adicionar recursos ou links relacionados
>
> [TJ Crowder](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/313877/4843158)

Achei que essa resposta explica muito bem o que foi dito [no chat hoje (12/08/2016)](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11910/estouro-de-pilha).

#### Essa resposta esta correta?

Se está correta ou não, eu não sou a melhor pessoa para dizer. Porém, eu discordo em um ponto específico, que é: "**Se você ver algo que precisa ser melhorado, clique em editar"**.

Uma edição, substancial, em uma resposta pode alterar o sentido da resposta. Se o Autor da Resposta (AR) não adicionou o texto, pode ter algum motivo para isso. Desde o momento que a resposta não faça parte da [wiki da comunidade](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/the-future-of-community-wiki), eu considero que a resposta é da autoridade do AR, e não da comunidade. Se tem algo para acrescentar, pode comentar com o AR nos comentários solicitando as melhorias/explicações, se esse for o caso.

#### Quando devemos alterar?

Acho que uma alteração de uma resposta deve ocorrer somente no intuito de corrigir algo. Isso porque se o AR não postou algo, deve ter algum motivo. Se acha que a resposta pode ser melhor, comente, converse com o AR, isso pode ajudar ele mesmo a melhorar a resposta, e caso ele não saiba, é melhor ele buscar informação e aprender realmente, do que você "forçar" ele a aprender editando a resposta.

#### Mas então, devo criar uma resposta nova apenas para acrescentar algo?

Porque não?

O intuito do site não é "prover conteúdo"? O fato de ter respostas parecidas faz exatamente isso. Eu posso ler uma resposta e não entender, porém, posso ler uma resposta que quer dizer a mesma coisa, mas escrita de forma diferente, que entenderei. As vezes a forma que algo está escrito muda totalmente o entendimento, e é essencial ressaltar isso.

Se sua resposta irá acrescentar algo a resposta anterior, pode responder dando o crédito à resposta anterior, isso não é errado (**se sua ideia é apenas ajudar, não ligará para aceitação da sua resposta como a melhor**).

#### Conclusão Pessoal

Acho que o simples fato de editar uma resposta para adicionar mais informações do que o AR colocou é algo rude e pode ser considerado ofensivo. Pode-se imaginar que está insinuando que ele não saiba o que você colocou. Claro, isso é uma forma de se ver e não uma "regra".

Até mesmo o fato de colocar o exemplo em um snippet/fiddle é algo desnecessário, sem comentários ou alguma interação com o AR anteriormente. Não custa nada você pedir, de forma educada, para o AR complementar a resposta. Acho isso válido e acrescenta mais valor do que editar a resposta "forçadamente".

> **Nota:** Ressalvo que esse ponto de vista é somente sobre as respostas. Perguntas possuem outras peculiaridades e devem ser tratadas de forma diferente, pois afinal, é algo diferente.

Comment: Concordo em gênero, número e grau :)

Answer (score 3):

Eu não "reverti" sua edição. Na minha opinião, as informações que você adicionou eram bastante úteis, e complementavam muito bem a resposta. Só acho que nao justificava o acréscimo de

> ## Um Título
>
> Seguido de
>
> > Um parágrafo de citação em inglês
>
> Seguido de
>
> > Outro parágrafo de citação, que só traduziu a primeira citação

Tudo isso pra dar uma informação simples:
O AngularJS bloqueia o `action` padrão de formulários, exceto quando explícito.

Achei que atrapalhava a leitura da resposta, a tornava muito extensa, e carregada de formatação, sem necessidade. Dar informações completas é excelente, fazê-lo de forma fácil de ler e absorver é melhor ainda.

Edições tem que ser como ninjas: **Numerosas, fortes e sutis.**<sup>1</sup>

---

Agora partindo pra sua pergunta original. Sua edição deve sempre fazer pelo menos uma dessas duas coisas: **corrigir** e **complementar**.

"Complementar" é um conceito simples de entender. Ajuda todo mundo, não avacalha com o que já existe, melhora o conteúdo. Todo mundo sai ganhando. O poder de adicionar informações relevantes à qualquer coisa no site é uma das maiores ferramentas do site. Ajuda a manter nosso conteúdo atualizado e de alta qualidade.

"Corrigir" é, também, um conceito simples de entender mas, acredito, mais difícil de aplicar. Se uma resposta está *errada*, faz mais sentido dar apresentar uma outra solução, alternativa e correta, ao problema. Escreva a sua resposta, vote contra a errada, deixe um comentário e siga em frente. Mas isso se a resposta *estiver errada*.

Mas a resposta pode apenas *ter um erro* (ou dois... ou cinco) e nesses casos vale a pena corrigir. Não tem porque adicionar uma outra resposta dizendo a mesma coisa, só mudando uma coisa aqui ou ali. **Respostas precisam ser fundamentalmente diferentes entre si**, caso contrário é difícil saber qual a "melhor", e os votos passam a ser muito mais subjetivos do que gostaríamos.

A linha entre "ter um erro" e "errada" é turva...
Talvez a melhor maneira de julgar isso seja pensando "*O que eu faria de diferente?*"

Se você escreveria praticamente a mesma coisa, com algumas mudanças, é provável que uma edição seja o caminho a ser seguido. Mas se a sua resposta apresentaria outra solução, outra abordagem, parte de premissas diferentes, então vá em frente e escreva a sua. Comente na respota anterior o que você vê de errado, indique a sua como solucionou esses erros.

Das duas maneiras, a comunidade sai ganhando.

---

<sup>**1.** Se você acha que ninjas não são numerosos, isso é exatamente o que eles querem que você ache</sup>

Comment: Fino de garagem essa resposta

Comment: Se eu fosse responder, ia tocar no ponto de sugerir ao usuário a mudança, em vez de por a mão, a não ser que fosse uma correção de coisa óbvia, mas essa é só a minha opinião, e eu provavelmente não vou postar uma resposta :)

Comment: @Bacco A qualidade do SOpt vai cair, e a **culpa é toda sua**. Mas, de qualquer maneira, Meta é sempre um caso à parte.

Comment: @Gabe e se a melhoria na resposta ou explicação que for acrescentada não for de encontro com as intenções do autor da resposta (AR)? Acho que esse comportamento de completar respostas básicas vai trazer muitos problemas futuros na analise de edições e um sem número de edições para melhorar conteúdo. Eu costumo fazer um comentário, ou se conhecer o AR até sou capaz de editar se for um erro que eu ache que foi falta de atenção do AR. Acho que até hoje raramente vi pessoas a complementar respostas como nesse caso. Será boa ideia ir por esse caminho?

Comment: Ah fui eu que dei o -1 por não concordar com essa ideia de complementar resposta.

Comment: Compartilho da opinião de ambos (Bacco e Jorge B), por isso o meu negativo também